# StreamSockets in Windows 8 javascript app

Tags: javascript, sockets, networking, microsoft-metro

I'm quite new to the world of networking and I'm trying to create a Windows 8 Metro style app that needs networking.

I basically want to connect 2 computers over the internet using `StreamSockets`.

I've been able to connect 2 different apps running on the same computer by using `"localhost"` as host name. (just as they did in the official Microsoft StreamSocket Sample).

However I'm not sure what should the host name be if I'll be connecting two computers over the internet.

Thanks

Comment: It would most likely be the computers IP address... `localhost` would resolve to `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: I thought it should be an IP address. But I'm not sure how can I get them if they're not in the same network as my computer is.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are two different scenarios for accessing remote computers:

1. If the computer you want to connect to is a home computer and  connects to internet through an network provider, DSL, and the public IP (the one which internet sees) is not dedicated (fixed), then you probably have to configure the Router with "www.dyndns.org" (or any other ) the router will update the IP when it changes. You have to name the computer, something like "myfriend.myhouse.net". If the IP is fixed, it does not change when the router is turn off/on then use the IP directly instead of a host name. See http://www.whatismyip.com/
   In either case, you need to open ports in the router (NAT) so that the router sends the packets to the right internal IP. Read the router's manual for help.
2. If the computer you want to connect to belongs to a domain, enterprise, then you need to talk with their network admin team. They can open or give you access to their network.

Once these are resolve, you can connect to the computer using the above host: "myfriend.myhouse.net" instead of "localhost".

More help can be found asking in internet about "remote desktop" or "accessing my home computer remotely"

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer. What if I want to create a multiplayer game? One of the two computers that play a sesion will also act as host? How can the client find out it's IP and connect to it? Thanks.

Comment: To find the IP address of a computer you need a host name, for example, myname.myhost.net. This domain can be purchase, see http://www.dyndns.org, is the one I use. You can buy one domain and have several computers in different places; computerONE.mydoain.net, computerTWO.mydomain.net, etc. These computers propagate their IP address through the router or with a special program running in each computer which update the host's IP in your DNS provider, for example dyndns.

Comment: Yes, I do understand this now. However, if 2 random players download and play my multiplayer game, I'll have a script create a Socket server on one of their computers. The other has to find the server's IP address that won't be using a DNS provider. Basically the two computers will connect directly. Is there a way for the client to find out the server's IP address without a DNS provider? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could it be that I'm missing something in your question but, as long as I know, there is nothing that substitutes a DNS. I'm afraid you must have a DNS for the client to find the Server IP. That's what you do when you connect to any WEB page. They need to be in a DNS so the browser can find its IP, unless you know its IP address.  Also, you can inform your clients, by phone or email, the new IP and put in your game an input box where the clients can enter the IP every time they connect to the server.